# Swift OneSignal OSPermissionSubscriptionState setSubscription

Tags: swift, cocoapods, onesignal

I had updated my cocoapods and am getting errors with OneSignal.

ERROR'S

Type 'OneSignal' has no member 'setSubscription'

```
OneSignal.setSubscription(true)
```

Cannot find type 'OSPermissionSubscriptionState' in scope

```
let status: OSPermissionSubscriptionState = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()
```

This code has compiled before running updates.

I am also getting "Type 'OneSignal' has no member 'setSubscription'

old

```
OneSignal.setSubscription(true)
```

new

```
OneSignal.disablePush(false)
```

old

```
func onOSSubscriptionChanged(_ stateChanges: OSSubscriptionStateChanges!) {
        if !stateChanges.from.status && stateChanges.to.subscribed {
            print("Subscribed for OneSignal push notifications!")
            // get player ID
            stateChanges.to.userId
            print(userID)
            print("************************")
        }
        print("SubscriptionStateChange: \n\(stateChanges)")
    }
```

new

```
func onOSPermissionChanged(_ stateChanges: OSPermissionStateChanges!) {
          // Example of detecting answering the permission prompt
          if stateChanges.from.status == OSNotificationPermission.notDetermined {
             if stateChanges.to.status == OSNotificationPermission.authorized {
                let deviceState = OneSignal.getDeviceState()
                let userID = deviceState?.userId
                print(userID)
                print("************************")
                print("Thanks for accepting notifications!")
             } else if stateChanges.to.status == OSNotificationPermission.denied {
                print("Notifications not accepted. You can turn them on later under your iOS settings.")
             }
          }
          // prints out all properties
          print("PermissionStateChanges: \n\(stateChanges)")
       }
```

You can also pull a Users OneSignal information like this

```
 let status: OSPermissionSubscriptionState =        OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()
  // Push Status Methods
 let hasPrompted = status.permissionStatus.hasPrompted
 print("hasPrompted: ", hasPrompted)
  let userStatus = status.permissionStatus.status
  print("userStatus: ", userStatus)
  let isSubscribed = status.subscriptionStatus.subscribed
  print("isSubscribed: ", isSubscribed)
  let userSubscriptionSetting =                      status.subscriptionStatus.userSubscriptionSetting
  print("userSubscriptionSetting: ", userSubscriptionSetting)
  if let userID = status.subscriptionStatus.userId{
  print("userID: ", userID)
}
   if let pushToken = status.subscriptionStatus.pushToken {
  print("pushToken: ", pushToken)
}
  // Email Status Methods
  if let emailPlayerId = status.emailSubscriptionStatus.emailUserId   {
  print("emailPlayerId: ", emailPlayerId)
}
  if let emailAddress = status.emailSubscriptionStatus.emailAddress   {
  print("emailAddress: ", emailAddress)
} 
 let isEmailSubscribed = status.emailSubscriptionStatus.subscribed
 print("isEmailSubscribed: ", isEmailSubscribed)
```

**OneSignal Wrong Documentation**

```
// START OneSignal initialization code
      let onesignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false, kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: false]
      
      // Replace 'YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID' with your OneSignal App ID.
      OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
        appId: "KEY",
        handleNotificationAction: nil,
        settings: onesignalInitSettings)

      OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification;
      //END OneSignal initializataion code
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be this will help you to get the new OneSignal use. I just updated my SDK to the 3.1.0, and I had to change some points:

New initialization:  [Link1](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup)

```
import UIKit
import OneSignal

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  
  // Remove this method to stop OneSignal Debugging 
  OneSignal.setLogLevel(.LL_VERBOSE, visualLevel: .LL_NONE)

  // OneSignal initialization
  OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
  OneSignal.setAppId("YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID")

  // promptForPushNotifications will show the native iOS notification permission prompt.
  // We recommend removing the following code and instead using an In-App Message to prompt for notification permission (See step 8)
  OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
    print("User accepted notifications: \(accepted)")
  })

   return true
}
  
// Remaining contents of your AppDelegate Class...
}
```

And in scope: [Link2](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk)

```
if let deviceState = OneSignal.getDeviceState() {
    let userId = deviceState.userId
    let pushToken = deviceState.pushToken
    let subscribed = deviceState.isSubscribed
 }
```

EDIT:
I think the code you pick up is from this [link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/step-by-step-ios-native-2x-to-300-upgrade-guide)
and just downstair, it says that the new initlialization is that:

Replace with the following

```
// OneSignal initialization
OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
OneSignal.setAppId("YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID")
```

Comment: Can you check my new edit? OneSignal documentation is wrong and am trying to figure out what the correct code is

Comment: Should I just remove "let onesignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false, kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: false]" and "OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification;" Because I am getting errors "Cannot find 'kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt' in scope" and "Cannot find 'kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL' in scope" and "Cannot find 'OSNotificationDisplayType' in scope"

Comment: @LukasBimba yep for me you have to remove it. I removed it in mine and it works like a charm 

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you can get the userId in one signal.

```
   if let deviceState = OneSignal.getDeviceState() {
        // Get the OneSignal Push Player Id
        let userId = deviceState.userId
        print("OneSignal Push Player ID: ", userId ?? "called too early, not set yet")

    }
```

Comment: Like the accepted answer says...