# "Cannot find type 'OSPermissionSubscriptionState in scope" error when using oneSignal with swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I started using oneSignal by one of tutorials. And when typing `let status: OSPermissionSubscriptionState = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()` i'm getting error `Cannot find type 'OSPermissionSubscriptionState'`. I don't know why it's happening because i founded this code in the [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sdk-reference) of oneSignal in User Status methods.

Comment: Which oneSignal version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Onegnal.getDeviceState()` instead of `getPermissionSubscriptionState`. You can follow this [documentation](http://Use%20%60Onegnal.getDeviceState()%60%20instead%20of%20%60getPermissionSubscriptionState%60.%20You%20can%20follow%20this%20%5Bhttps://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/30-api-reference-ios#setnotificationwillshowinforegroundhandler-method%5D).

Comment: Thank you. I already found answer. Thats right! but i couldn't open your link. Is that right link? https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/30-api-reference-ios . Look's like its easier to find new methods in `Other methods` paragraph. (you can find it in right side of web page)

Answer (score 0):

you can apply my answer here. In which server you are using, you can save the id to the server.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73744275/15297337

Comment: If the question already has an answer then you can simply mark it as a duplicate or add the answer link in comments.